# missing wsse security header in request while running axis2 rampart

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis, rampart

> I am developing web service using axis2 1.6.4 with transport level security and username token authentication using eclipse europa ide.I have created web service and deploy to axis2.Its working successfully on local project ,but when i run on axis2 server its showing error 
>   "missing wsse:security header in request".So please advice me any solution for this problem.
>   here is my services.xml

```
    <service name="Temp_Secure" >
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">rampart.service.Temp_Secure</parameter>
    <module ref="addressing"/>
<module ref="rampart"/>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UTOverTransport" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
          <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:TransportToken>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Basic256/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <sp:Layout>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Lax/>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy"> 
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>rampart.service.PWCBHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
            </ramp:RampartConfig>       
          </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy> 

</service>
```

and here is client code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException  {
    ConfigurationContext ctx = null;
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/server1.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "admin1");
        try {
            ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("../Ws-Client/WebContent/WEB-INF", "../Ws-Client/WebContent/WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml");
        } catch (AxisFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    Temp_SecureStub stub = null;
    try {
        stub = new Temp_SecureStub(ctx,"https://localhost:8443/axis2/services/Temp_Secure");
    } catch (AxisFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();

    try {
        sc.engageModule("rampart");
    } catch (AxisFault e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Options options = sc.getOptions();
    options.setUserName("apache");
    options.setPassword("admin1");


    float celciusValue = 0;
    float farnht = 0;
    try {
        celciusValue = stub.farenhit2Celcius(100);
        farnht = stub.celcius2Farenhit(100);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();    
    }
    System.out.println("farenhit value for 100 c is : " + celciusValue);
    System.out.println("farenhit value for 100 c is : " + farnht);

}
```

and here is client axis2.xml

```
    <axisconfig name="AxisJava2.0">
<module ref="rampart"/>



    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Parameters -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <parameter name="hotdeployment">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="hotupdate">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableMTOM">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableSwA">false</parameter>



    <parameter name="EnableChildFirstClassLoading">false</parameter>


    <parameter name="exposeServiceMetadata">true</parameter>



    <!--This will give out the timout of the configuration contexts, in milliseconds-->
    <parameter name="ConfigContextTimeoutInterval">30000</parameter>

    <parameter name="sendStacktraceDetailsWithFaults">false</parameter>

    <parameter name="DrillDownToRootCauseForFaultReason">false</parameter>

    <parameter name="userName">admin</parameter>
    <parameter name="password">axis2</parameter>


    <parameter name="disableREST" locked="false">false</parameter>

    <!-- Following parameter will suppress generation of SOAP 1.2 bindings in auto-generated WSDL files -->
    <parameter name="disableSOAP12" locked="true">false</parameter>

    <!--POJO deployer , this will alow users to drop .class file and make that into a service-->
    <deployer extension=".class" directory="pojo" class="org.apache.axis2.deployment.POJODeployer"/>
    <deployer extension=".jar" directory="servicejars"
              class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer"/>
    <deployer extension=".jar" directory="transports"
              class="org.apache.axis2.deployment.TransportDeployer"/>


    <parameter name="useGeneratedWSDLinJAXWS">false</parameter>

    <!--    The way of adding listener to the system-->
    <!--    <listener class="org.apache.axis2.ObserverIMPL">-->
    <!--        <parameter name="RSS_URL">http://127.0.0.1/rss</parameter>-->
    <!--    </listener>-->

    <threadContextMigrators>
        <threadContextMigrator listId="JAXWS-ThreadContextMigrator-List"
                               class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.addressing.migrator.EndpointContextMapMigrator"/>
    </threadContextMigrators>

    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2006/01/wsdl/in-only"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2006/01/wsdl/in-out"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>

    <messageFormatters>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
    </messageFormatters>


    <messageBuilders>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/>
    </messageBuilders>

    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Transport Ins -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <transportReceiver name="http"
                       class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
        <parameter name="port">8081</parameter>

    </transportReceiver>
 <transportReceiver name="https"
                       class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
        <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
        </transportReceiver>

    <transportSender name="local"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender"/>
    <transportSender name="http"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
        <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
        <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>


    </transportSender>

    <transportSender name="https"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
        <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
        <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>
    </transportSender>

    <module ref="addressing"/>
 <module ref="rampart"/>

    <clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="false">


        <parameter name="AvoidInitiation">true</parameter>


        <parameter name="membershipScheme">multicast</parameter>

        <!--
         The clustering domain/group. Nodes in the same group will belong to the same multicast
         domain. There will not be interference between nodes in different groups.
        -->
        <parameter name="domain">wso2.carbon.domain</parameter>

        <parameter name="synchronizeAll">true</parameter>

        <!--
          The maximum number of times we need to retry to send a message to a particular node
          before giving up and considering that node to be faulty
        -->
        <parameter name="maxRetries">10</parameter>

        <!-- The multicast address to be used -->
        <parameter name="mcastAddress">228.0.0.4</parameter>

        <!-- The multicast port to be used -->
        <parameter name="mcastPort">45564</parameter>

        <!-- The frequency of sending membership multicast messages (in ms) -->
        <parameter name="mcastFrequency">500</parameter>

        <!-- The time interval within which if a member does not respond, the member will be
         deemed to have left the group (in ms)
         -->
        <parameter name="memberDropTime">3000</parameter>

        <!--
           The IP address of the network interface to which the multicasting has to be bound to.
           Multicasting would be done using this interface.
        -->
        <parameter name="mcastBindAddress">127.0.0.1</parameter>

        <!-- The host name or IP address of this member -->
        <parameter name="localMemberHost">127.0.0.1</parameter>

        <!--
        The TCP port used by this member. This is the port through which other nodes will
        contact this member
         -->
        <parameter name="localMemberPort">4000</parameter>

        <!--
        Preserve message ordering. This will be done according to sender order.
        -->
        <parameter name="preserveMessageOrder">true</parameter>

        <!--
        Maintain atmost-once message processing semantics
        -->
        <parameter name="atmostOnceMessageSemantics">true</parameter>

        <!--
        Properties specific to this member
        -->
        <parameter name="properties">
            <property name="backendServerURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/services/"/>
            <property name="mgtConsoleURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/"/>
        </parameter>

        <members>
            <member>
                <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>
            <member>
                <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
                <port>4001</port>
            </member>
        </members>


        <groupManagement enable="false">
            <applicationDomain name="apache.axis2.application.domain"
                               description="Axis2 group"
                               agent="org.apache.axis2.clustering.management.DefaultGroupManagementAgent"/>
        </groupManagement>


        <nodeManager class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.management.DefaultNodeManager"
                         enable="true"/>


        <stateManager class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.state.DefaultStateManager"
                      enable="true">
            <replication>
                <defaults>
                    <exclude name="local_*"/>
                    <exclude name="LOCAL_*"/>
                </defaults>
                <context class="org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext">
                    <exclude name="local_*"/>
                </context>
                <context class="org.apache.axis2.context.ServiceGroupContext">
                    <exclude name="local_*"/>
                </context>
                <context class="org.apache.axis2.context.ServiceContext">
                    <exclude name="local_*"/>
                </context>
            </replication>
        </stateManager>
    </clustering>

    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Phases  -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <phaseOrder type="InFlow">
        <!--  System predefined phases       -->
        <phase name="Transport">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Addressing">
            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Addressing"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="GenericProviderDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.GenericProviderDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <!--  System predefined phases       -->
        <!--   After Postdispatch phase module author or service author can add any phase he want      -->
        <phase name="OperationInPhase">
            <handler name="MustUnderstandChecker"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.MustUnderstandChecker">
                <order phase="OperationInPhase"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="OutFlow">
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
        <phase name="OperationOutPhase"/>
        <!--system predefined phase-->
        <!--these phase will run irrespective of the service-->
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
        <phase name="Security"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="InFaultFlow">
        <phase name="Addressing">
            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Addressing"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="GenericProviderDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.GenericProviderDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.dispatchers.MustUnderstandValidationDispatcher"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="OperationInFaultPhase"/>
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="OutFaultFlow">
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>
        <phase name="OperationOutFaultPhase"/>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
        <phase name="Security"/>
    </phaseOrder>
</axisconfig>

and PWCBHandler class

    public class PWCBHandler  implements CallbackHandler {

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {

        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {

            // Client uses this callbackt o retrieve the password 

            WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback)callbacks[i];

            if(pwcb.getIdentifier().equals("apache")) {
                pwcb.setPassword("admin1");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is stack Trace

```
   [ERROR] Missing wsse:Security header in request
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:186)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at rampart.client.Temp_SecureStub.farenhit2Celcius(Temp_SecureStub.java:451)
    at rampart.client.TempConvClient.main(TempConvClient.java:128)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Missing wsse:Security header in request
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:110)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please anyone who knows how to overcome to this problem.

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: I have added stack trace above.

Comment: On the client-side, do you get an exception where you do try {
        sc.engageModule("rampart");
    } catch (AxisFault e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } ?

Comment: On this below line its throwing error                   try {
        celciusValue = stub.farenhit2Celcius(100);
        farnht = stub.celcius2Farenhit(100);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();    
    }